# Scala structured data extraction via regex and pattern matching

Tags: regex, scala, pattern-matching

Given structured data in a string format how do I extract parts of the data effectively using pattern matching and regular expressions?

Example:

```
val input = Seq("name-12345","inval1d-12345","invalid-12here123","hello-54321","inval1d-1aa2")

case class Client(name:Option[String],clientID:Option[Int])

def parseClient(input:String):Option[Client] = {
  val clientRegex = """([a-zA-Z]+)-([0-9]+)""".r
  Option(input).flatMap(in => {
    in match {
      case clientRegex(name,clientID) => Some(Client(Some(name),Some(clientID.toInt)))
      case _ => None
    }
  })
}

input.map(parseClient)
```

The issue with this however is that if I fail to validate a single part of the structured data then I parse None of it.

How could I use regular expressions to define in a hierarchical manor such as:

```
val nameRegex = """([a-zA-Z]+)""".r
val clientIDRegex = """([0-9]+)""".r
```

Then match these combined within a pattern?

The output from the example:

```
Seq(
 Some(Client(Some("name"),Some(12345)))
 ,None
 ,None
 ,Some(Client(Some("hello"),Some(54321)))
 ,None
)
```

The required output:

```
Seq(
 Some(Client(Some("name"),Some(12345)))
 ,Some(Client(None,Some(12345)))
 ,Some(Client(Some("invalid"),None))
 ,Some(Client(Some("hello"),Some(54321)))
 ,None
)
```

Comment: What is the expected output for the input you provided?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I have edited the question, apologies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should give the expected outcome:

```
val input = Seq("name-12345", "inval1d-12345", "invalid-12here123", "hello-54321")

case class Client(name: Option[String], clientID: Option[Int])

def parseClient(input: String): Option[Client] = {
  val clientRegex = """(?:([a-zA-Z^-]+)|[^-]*)-(?:([0-9]+)|.*)""".r
  input match {
    case clientRegex(null, null) => None
    case clientRegex(name, id) => Some(Client(Option(name), Option(id).map(_.toInt)))
    case _ =>
      None
  }
}

input.map(parseClient)
```

I removed the flatMap construct since this was unnecessary.
Interesting part here is the regex:

```
"""(?:([a-zA-Z^-]+)|[^-]*)-(?:([0-9]+)|.*)"""
```

I made changed it so it expects either the correct values and therefore captures it in the group ( `([a-zA-Z^-]+)` for name and `([0-9]+)` for id ) but also added the other cases (no valid name or id). Everything is in non-capture groups (?:) so it is grouped correctly.

If something is not as expected in the capture groups, the group will be null, which is handled in the match-case.

EDIT 
Made a correction to the code so that it works for completely invalid input and removed unnecessary if-statements

EDIT 2
Adapted the code according to comment of OP taking advantage of Option(null) => None evaluation

Comment: thank you, I eventually used this but I changed the cases to:
case clientRegex(null,null) => None

case clientRegex(name,clientID) => Some(Client(Option(name),Option(clientID).map(_.toInt)))

case _ => None

Comment: Nice one, didn't even know, that Option(null) evaluates to None. Will adapt the code

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for something like applicative you can chain.
you can do something like this using the `Validated` type from cats:

```
val houseNumber = parseClient("house_number").andThen{ n =>
   if (isValid(n)) Validated.valid(n)
   else Validated.invalid(ParseError("house_number"))
}
```

and
I would opt to using to [atto](https://github.com/tpolecat/atto):
it has the `ParseResult` type the keeps all the information on parsing the string.

Comment: Sorry I don't think I explained myself properly, please look at the expected output

Comment: @AdamPitt it's trivial to map the `ParseResult` to your expected output and the upside is that you won't have to implement this yourself.